# How to check if object is referenced before deleting

Tags: java, hibernate

I have java application with web interface (Spring MVC) using Hibernate. I have quite simple DB scheme here with a *Group* entity which you can add/delete on one webpage. Then there is another *Entity* having *Group* as field therefor *Entity* has a FK to *Group*. Note that there might be generally many other entities referencing my *Group*.

If I want to delete *Group* object it might fail on FK constraint - the group is referenced by some other entity.

Is there a way how to perform a check wheter my *Group* is referenced and the delete will fail rather then performing the delete and catching the exception? What is the best practice here?

Thanks

**NOTE**: Just to be clear, simple select is not a solution since the *Group* might be referenced generaly by many other tables, not only one.

Comment: Did you find a good solution? I have the same case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checking before deleting is less efficient, and might still lead to a constraint violation if some link is added by another transaction between the moment you check and the moment you delete.

On the other hand, it allows displaying a more specific error message to the user (like "the group is still referenced by a FooBar").

Just do what you feel is best in your specific case. Note however that if some exception happens, the whole transaction should be rolled back, and the session should be closed, because such an exception leaves the session in an inconsistent state. Moreover, it's not the delete, but the flush or the commit that will throw the exception.

Now, if you want to check, there is no magical solution. You might have bidirectional associations, and you could thus check that `group.getUsers()` is emtpy (although this will fetch all the users of the group). Or you could execute dedicated queries like `select count(user.id) from User user where user.group = :group` to know if the group is still referenced. But you need to do one of those for every possible reference to the group.

Comment: What if I have the the 'group' referenced from 6 other tables? Then neither the query nor the bi-directional solution seems to be good ... So you would recommend perform the delete and handle the exception?

Comment: As I said, you need to do that for every reference (Users, Foos, Bars, etc.). If the exception is more frequent than no exception, and if you need to tell the user which entity still references the group, I would go with the check. If you just need some generic error message, I would go with the exception.

Comment: +1 sofar, but not solved - I definitely would like to have some more specific message. The exception being thrown is JpaSystemException - doesn't tell much. The message would be way to general. The ConstraintValidationException is like 4th cause in the chain ... I would be happy if I can say 'Cannot delete because the object is referenced', not necessary to tell who references it.

Comment: @Jan, why can't you just catch the ConstraintViolationException specifically and return the error message for that case?

Comment: That actually appears as another super problem :) The exception is translated from spring as JPASystemException. The causes are: JPASystemException -> PersistenceException->CinstraintValidationException. It gets somehow wrongly translated into this generic exception ... I searched through few spring forums and this appears to be a big problem on its own. If I make it translate into specific Spring Exception I will be happy again

Comment: I went with the bi-directional associations. It appeared my question turned out to exception translations but JB had a point here. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You could perform a `SELECT COUNT` on Entity based on the Group's ID and then only attempt a Group deletion if the returned value is 0.

What's wrong with surrounding your delete with try/catch?

Comment: That is why I wrote 'it might be referenced by many other different entities'. I ment it might be referenced from 6 other tables which will make the chceck difficult to do and maintain.

Comment: And the exception being thrown is JpaSystemException ... the ConstraintViolationException is like 4th cause in the chain. Doesn't look right to me to iterate through the causes. And it definitely doesn't look like best practice to me :)

Comment: So what you're saying is that you have 6 other tables which may have a foreign key pointing at Group? Is it possible to normalise these tables?

Comment: Consider it a general question, maybe my example wasn't best. Imagine the schema is optimalised. It is still OK to have many tables referencing my single group.

Answer (score 0):

With using JPA you normally should also have collections of references in your domainobject Group. So before deleting the group, you could check if all those collections are empty. But keep in mind, that this might cost some extra time before deleting, but could be necessary to inform the user about the currently associated objects, when delete fails.

Comment: Why 'should' I have the reverse collections? Any advantage beside checking if reference exists? The check will load all the collections from DB which seems to be 'expensive' jsut for the checking purposes.

Comment: yes, it can idd be expensive. There are no obvious advantages, unless you often need those references anyway and might even have to eager fetch them when entity gets loaded, meaning you have those information loaded already anyway. Its like Nizet already pointed out. It just depends on your requirements. When you need those detailed information for the user, you might wonna go with it. Else you just give back some sort of generic error message.